# Relation between monero jobs (blob) and new blocks

Tags: mining-pools, mining-theory, mining-pool-setup

When you are mining in a Monero pool (e.g.,https://minexmr.com/) you keep on receiving jobs from it. These contain the blob which, after some processing, is mined by the miners.

Different jobs received from the pool can refer to the same previous block. In fact, the prev_id of the block header (first part of the blob) across different jobs received from the pool could be the same. I couldn't find as specific answer to the following questions:

1. When does the pool decide to send out a new job also with the same prev_id (which should mean that no new block has been mined yet)?
2. Does each miner already connected receive the same job message?
3. If a miner is working on an job that has the same prev_id of the one received does him stop and starts to work on the new one immediately? I know this is true if a new block has been mined but in this case the prev_id changes.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Pools send a new job when they see a new blockchain height, in response to a `getjob` request, in response to a `login` request or sending a job to a miner with a new difficulty. `prev_id` will stay the same so long as the blockchain height is the same.
2. Almost exactly the same job. Each miners job is identical except for the jobs extra field in the blob which makes each job unique for each miner. The pool updates this field for each miner before sending.
3. This is up to the miner implementation. A miner should ideally stop mining a previous job when they are notified of a new job, but there's no harm in finishing the existing one before starting the new one as most pools will still accept shares from recent jobs.

Comment: Does new blockchain height means that a new block has been mined? if so why isn't then the prev_id changing? Thank you I'll mark yours as best answer if no one else answers soon.

Comment: Every time the blockchain height increases, it is because a new block has been mined (disregarding reorgs here). That newly mined block points to (via prev_id) the block below it (prev_id is the block id at height-1). When the height is increased, a new block template must be sent to miners. The block template will have it's prev_id set to the highest block on the blockchain.

Comment: Then how do you explain my 1st question? I'm telling you that pools send out different jobs but with the same prev_id in the blob. You answered saying that the Blockchain height has increased but this is not true if the prev_id is the same. I don't quite understand.

Comment: Well of course a pool continues to send jobs with same prev_id until height changes. Miners don't all ask for block templates at the same time and every time an individual miner submits, they need a new job, which will have same prev_id if the height has not changed.

Comment: Further, there are 2 points jobs get sent to miners. 1, when the height increases, 2, when a miner submits work.

Comment: Well, it is not true that as soon as I submit a share I receive a new job. I can submit multiple shares for the same job. That's why I need a clarification on when the pool sends a new job to my miner. If the height increases ok, it makes sense. But if the height stays the same, why do I receive multiple jobs with the same prev_id but different transactions? Based on what a pool sends out a new job? And the answer is not beacuse I have submitted work.

Comment: Not quite. If you submit a job with the same nonce, it is marked as a duplicate share by the pool. The only scenario you can be awarded shares for the same job is if you submitted the same job with two valid but different nonces.

Comment: Also note your miner can ask for multiple jobs. Each job will be different (because of the extra field in the blob returned) but would have the same height (assuming chain length not changed between requests), and in this scenario, prev_id would also match.

Comment: of course I wasn't talking about two submission with the same nonce. and usually the miner doesn't ask for jobs but receive them. Right?

Comment: Wrong. A miner can absolutely request a job. The current implementations of stratum in use on monero pools have the methods: `login`, `submit` and `getjob`. Both `login` and `getjob` return jobs.

Comment: Pools also send miners jobs without one being requested. They send the new job to all connected clients when the blockchain height changes. As I answered your original question.

Comment: If you mine for example with xmrig there is no such a thing as <getjob>. I'm telling you that I receive new jobs, without issuing any request, that have the same prev_id but different merkle root for example. When and why does it happen?

Comment: xmrrig is not a pool, it's the miner. The pool implements the method `getjob`. https://github.com/Snipa22/nodejs-pool/blob/0fcabef6d328b159ef429ea4b6b092e6f7c78006/lib/pool.js#L727

Comment: "I'm telling you that I receive new jobs, without issuing any request". Yes because the protocol is not just request-reponse. Pools can send new jobs whenever they like. Commonly this is either: in response to login, in response to getjob, after a submission response (such as to update difficulty of the job) or when blockchain height changes.

Comment: I'm asking client side. I run xmrig and I see new jobs but I don't know the reason why a pool should send me a new job, without me requesting it, with the same prev_id but a different Merkle tree hash.

Comment: And I have answered why you may get sent jobs with same prev_id.

Comment: You didn't answer why I receive different jobs if I don't ask for them and the Blockchain height is the same.

Comment: As I have said, you don't need to request (ask) for a new job. The protocol is not just request-response. A pool can send you a new job whenever. An example of which can be to update your jobs difficulty.

Comment: Ok thanks. We are getting close. I would like to know if there is a pool configuration to decide when to send a new job. Because whenever dosen't seem realistic.

Comment: See point 1 in the answer. And no, these are not configuration options.